# Brakes lock up when you put the vehicle in reverse

Tags: brakes, kia, sportage

My 2002 Kia Sportage's brakes are locking up when you put the vehicle in reverse. When you put it in drive or neutral the brakes release. When they lockup, it sounds like air pressure and the pedal goes down to the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Your rear brakes are drums, based on parts availability. My thinking is, some of the hardware on one side of your brakes has failed, but it is only evident when the vehicle is put into reverse. When in reverse, the shoes are pulled out of place, locking one of your wheels in place, and allows the brake cylinder to expand uncontrollably. When you put it back into drive, the brake shoe goes back into place, pushing the cylinder back into its proper position. (Mind you, this is only conjecture at this point due to the limited amount of information.)

You ***SHOULD NOT*** drive your vehicle until you get it figured out. This could be a huge issue which could cause you to completely lose your brakes while driving. If you don't have the means to do the work yourself at home, have it towed to a shop to get it fixed.

Answer (score -1):

The problem can easily get fixed by checking the spring from the hand brake that goes to your rear wheel. Adding a lubricant or wd40 and making sure the hand brake spring gets released will take care of it.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any relevance to the problem. Hand brake cable sticking would not only cause an issue when the car is put into reverse.